# How do I move all files from one folder to a subfolder except .html file using the command line?

Tags: command-line, mv

I would like to know how can I move all files from folder-A to folder-A's sub-folder except .html file with a command line.

Suppose I am in **dist** folder and there are 50 files and 5 folders. Now I would like to move all 50 files and 4 folders to one of the **subfolder** inside dist folder, without having to write all the files name.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Current directory:

```
$ ls -F
1   12  15  18  20  23  26  29  31  34  37  4   42  45  48  50  8       b.html  foldera/  folderd/
10  13  16  19  21  24  27  3   32  35  38  40  43  46  49  6   9       c.html  folderb/  foldere/
11  14  17  2   22  25  28  30  33  36  39  41  44  47  5   7   a.html  d.html  folderc/  moveHere/
```

Temporary enable shell *extglob* and disable history substitution:

```
$ shopt -s extglob; set +H
```

To move everything to a directory named "moveHere" excluding *html* files:

```
$ mv !(*.html|moveHere) moveHere/
```

Current directory after moving files:

```
$ ls
a.html  b.html  c.html  d.html  moveHere
```

Check new dir:

```
$ ls moveHere/
1   12  15  18  20  23  26  29  31  34  37  4   42  45  48  50  8        folderb  foldere
10  13  16  19  21  24  27  3   32  35  38  40  43  46  49  6   9        folderc
11  14  17  2   22  25  28  30  33  36  39  41  44  47  5   7   foldera  folderd
```

Comment: Getting error in my CLI:

bash: !: event not found

Comment: Updated the answer @i.maddy

Answer (score 0):

You can use `find` with `-not -name "..."` and `-exec mv`:

```
find . -maxedpth 1 \
  -not -name "subfolder" \
  -not -name "*.html" \
  -exec mv -t subfolder {} + \;
```